# Заминочка в выполнении PHP кода

Tags: база-данных, php, регистрация

Имеется вот такой код. Его суть - проверить, не существует ли похожое имя пользователя в базе. Если существует - дать отбой, если же нет, то добавить в базу. Одинаковые значения добавляются, словно этой проверки нет вовсе. Не могу разобрать, в чём проблема.

```
<?
require 'connect.php';

mysql_select_db('it');

$check_data = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login'='$_POST[login]'"; //проверка значений в базе
$rs         = mysql_query($check_data);
$num        = mysql_num_rows($rs);

if ($_POST['login'] != '') {
    if ($num == 0) {
        $SQLstr = "INSERT INTO users (login,password) VALUES('$_POST[login]','$_POST[password]')";
        $result = mysql_query($SQLstr);
        echo 'Вы добавлены в базу!';
    } else {
        echo 'Такое имя уже зарегистрировано!Будьте креативны!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Поле имени пустое!Заполните его!';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сюда бы еще обработку ошибок добавить не помешало, но принцип, думаю, Ясен:]

```
<?

function checkOrCreateLogin($login)
{
    // подключаемся к БД
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdatabase;host=127.0.0.1', 'db_user', 'db_password');
    // подготавливаем запрос на выборку id записей с логином $login
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`=:login;");
    // выполняем запрос
    $stmt->execute(array(":login" => $login));
    // Если количество возвращенных строк больше 0, значит логин уже существует
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Иначе добавляем новый логин
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`login`) VALUES(:login);");
        $stmt->execute(array(':login' => $login));
        // Возвращаем ID только что добавленного логина
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    }
}

var_dump(checkOrCreateLogin('ololosh'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в кавычках: названия таблиц [заключаются](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) (необязательно) в обратные одинарные кавычки "`". У вас сейчас это буквально строка "login", а не имя таблицы. Если только отвечать на суть вопроса, то так уже должно работать:

```
$check_data = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '%s', $_POST['login']);
```

Вот так чуть получше было бы:

```
require 'connect.php';
mysql_select_db('it');

$login = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$check_data = sprintf( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '%s'", $login);
$rs         = mysql_query($check_data);
$num        = mysql_result($rs, 0);
if ( !empty($login)) {
    if ($num > 0) {
        echo 'Такое имя уже зарегистрировано! Будьте креативны!';
    } else {
        $SQLstr = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`) VALUES ('%s','%s')",$login,$password);
        $result = mysql_query($SQLstr);
        echo 'Вы добавлены в базу!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Поле имени пустое! Заполните его!';
}
```