# Добавление в бд данных с кавычками

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Доброго дня

Хотел попробовать занести в таблицу mysql :

```
// работает
$param = "abc";
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`field`) VALUES ('".$param."')");

// не работает
$param = "`field`='05'";
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`field`) VALUES ('".$param."')");
```

Начал гуглить, эта штука называется sql инекция, и показано как от нее защититься. Как раз это не то, что ищу. охота добавить в бд нужное (и потом считать это). Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: Ммм... Правильно ли я вас понял? То есть, вы хотите не защиту от MySQL-инъекции, а как обойти её?

Comment: я просто хочу добавить в ячейку таблицы такую запись

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Экранирование](http://www.phpfaq.ru/slashes). Совсем не сложно использовать. А вообще желательно все данные, которые могут так или иначе оказаться в БД. Используйте экранирование суперглобальных массивов до того, как будете загружать страницу. В интернете много информации по тонкостям вопроса

Answer (score 2):

```
$param = "`field`='05'";
$param = mysql_real_escape_string($param);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`field`) VALUES ('".$param."')");
```

Если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: да. так оно и оказалось. акцепт правда влепил первому ответившему

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите вот [этот комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148570#148592). В нем приведен пример работы с БД используя [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)